# Как сделать триггер для контрола внутри компонента?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, wpf-шаблоны

Есть кастомный компонент из в другого файла. Как сделать триггер для контрола внутри компонента, не редактируя при этом сам шаблон компонента?

```
 <ctrl:NewNumSpinner Grid.Row="1" x:Name="nnsSelTime" IsEnabled="{Binding DelayTimeEnabled}" 
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Margin="0,-1,0,0"
                                        Value="{Binding Path=SelectedTime, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                        <ctrl:NewNumSpinner.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="ValueText"  Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="ValueText" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ctrl:NewNumSpinner.Resources>                    
                    </ctrl:NewNumSpinner>
```

Выдает ошибку. ValueText - имя этого контрола внутри компонента.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ValueText" Text="{Binding FormattedTime, ElementName=NewNumUpDown, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Переопределить `Template` например. Вы точно уверены, что у контрола нет подходящего DP, чтобы поменять этот цвет? В таком случае это промах разработчика данного контрола. Нужно либо добавить DP, либо переписать шаблон.

Comment: В том и дело, что лучше бы не переопределять сам темплейт.

Comment: Нужно видеть исходники существующего шаблона, чтобы понять, что именно вы хотите там переопределить. Без триггера то можете цвет поменять? И зачем 2 триггера, когда здесь одного хватит? На тру вставьте просто сеттер сверху, потом триггер на фолс.

Comment: Изменить нужно TextBlock с Name="ValueText" в зависимости от общекомпонентного IsEnabled

Comment: Ничего не получится через стиль, так как цвет задан явно аттрибутом. Если бы он не был задан, сработал бы стиль. Так что остается только через шаблон.